# Каким образом реализуются модули?

Tags: php

Каким образом реализуются модули такие как в 1с-битрикс, opencart и других cms?

Если можно с примером принципа работы

(когда в отдельной папке лежит модуль, он подключается и дальше расширяет функционал cms)

Comment: Пишите ядро и научите его подключать модули.

Answer (score 1):

лучше всего папки а в них классы. Ну и autoload в помощь.